# Point subdirectory to another domain is IIS 6

Tags: apache-2.2, url, iis-6, rewrite

Is it possible to rewrite somehow www.mysite.com/Pictures to point to test.mysite.com/Pictures
or even more broadly www.someothersite.com/Pictures ?

Note: www.mysite.com and test.mysite.com are on separate machines and built with different technologies (one is ASP.NET and the other is PHP) but I have access to both of them.

I want that when I reference a picture like www.mysite.com/Pictures/pic12345.png the picture to display correctly, even though there is not /Pictures folder on that server and the pictures has to be retrieved by going to test.mysite.com/Picture/pic12345.png

Ideally I want to do this in IIS6 to test it. However I am interested if it possible to do in any webserver (Apache, IIS7)

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I worked with Asp.NET but you could write a http module that handles this for you.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about that, for some reason, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a .htaccess file (on www.mysite.com), within which you want:

```
Redirect 301 /Pictures www.someothersite.com/Pictures
```

Alternatively, you could use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Pictures/(.*)$ www.someothersite.com/Pictures/$1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that work? if I have a picture like this <img src="http://www.mysite.com/Pictures/Pic12345.jpg" alt="some pick"/> will it display it correctly?

Comment: I think you might need ModRewrite for that usage. Hold on

Comment: Did both work, or just the second one?

Comment: Couldn't make it to work with neither yet, but it seems the second one is the right way to go, I will give it a few more tries or try variations of this.